# npm install vs. update - what's the difference?

Tags: node.js, npm

What is the practical difference between `npm install` and `npm update`? When should I use which?

Answer (score 799, accepted):

The difference between [npm install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) and [npm update](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update) handling of package versions specified in **package.json**:

```json
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "1.0",                               // install   update
  "dependencies": {                               // ------------------
    "already-installed-versionless-module": "*",  // ignores   "1.0" -> "1.1"
    "already-installed-semver-module": "^1.4.3"   // ignores   "1.4.3" -> "1.5.2"
    "already-installed-versioned-module": "3.4.1" // ignores   ignores
    "not-yet-installed-versionless-module": "*",  // installs  installs
    "not-yet-installed-semver-module": "^4.2.1"   // installs  installs
    "not-yet-installed-versioned-module": "2.7.8" // installs  installs
  }
}
```

**Summary**: The only big difference is that **an already installed module with fuzzy versioning** ...

- gets ignored by `npm install`
- gets updated by `npm update`

**Additionally**: `install` and `update` by default handle devDependencies differently

- `npm install` will **install/update** devDependencies unless `--production` flag is added
- `npm update` will **ignore** devDependencies unless `--dev` flag is added

---

**Why use `npm install` at all?**

Because `npm install` does more when you look besides handling your dependencies in `package.json`.
As you can see in [npm install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) you can ...

- manually install node-modules
- set them as *global* (which puts them in the shell's `PATH`) using `npm install -g <name>`
- install certain versions described by git tags
- install from a git url
- force a reinstall with `--force`

Comment: and what about `~1.3` ?

Comment: what if the version is like ^5.0.9? And is it possible to make `npm install --save somePackage` save the * to dependencies?

Comment: I've seen where npm install reports errors on missing dependencies and npm update does not.

Comment: I'd also note that scripts like `postinstall` run on install, but not on update.

Comment: If `install` and `update` work differently on git URLs, git tags, etc. specified in the `package.json` then it would be great to add those cases to the example.

Comment: @Offirmo the tilde in the fuzzy versioning means "update to the latest minor (bugfix) release of this package", the minor version being the last number in the version, i.e. `1.3.0 -> 1.3.1` This is similar to `^1.3.0`, where the `^` updates major version, i.e. `1.3.0 -> 1.4.0`.

Comment: @BoyanKushlev I think you mean minor and patch/bugfix, not major and minor. Major is 1 for all your examples.

Comment: Also, npm install will generate a `package-lock.json`

Comment: In what way does `npm update` **ignore** devDependencies? I don't know if that has changed since written or not, but when I run `npm update` on a fresh folder that has no node_modules at all, it does install those defined in the "devDependencies" section of package.json, without supplying a `--dev` flag.

Comment: And what about `dist-tag`s?

Comment: by "already installed" you mean dependency is already in node-modules or being in package-lock.json qualifies as "already installed"?

Comment: Looking at the current `npm` versions (8 and 9), the "update ignores dev versions if you don't use the `--dev`" flag is no longer true. Instead, it has the `--omit` flag. If that is not set explicitly, npm will check the `NODE_ENV` environment variable and if that is set to `production` it will omit the dev dependencies. Otherwise it will update *all* dependencies.

Comment: `install and update by default handle devDependencies differently` Thanks, I hate it. (/s)

Comment: the same behavior as `composer install/update`

Answer (score 111):

**npm install** installs all modules that are listed on `package.json` file and their dependencies.

**npm update** updates all packages in the `node_modules` directory and their dependencies.

**npm install express** installs only the express module and its dependencies.

**npm update express** updates express module (starting with npm@2.x, it doesn't update its dependencies).

So updates are for when you already have the module and wish to get the new version.

Comment: if you don't specify a particular version in a package.json file, npm install will get the latest version of a module. So this a kind of an update.

Comment: So what should I use, `npm install` or `npm update`? Or, in other words, I am now using `npm install` and it seems to do the updating as well, is there any reason why should I ever use `npm update`?

Comment: If you don't specify a version for you modules you can use keep using npm install to do updates. But generally its good idea to specify a module version in your package.json file. Then you can't use npm install to do updates.

Comment: So `update` will always update to the latest version, regardless of package.json, while `install` will respect the version given in package.json?

Comment: `update` installs (or updates to) latest version of module. `install` installs latest version of module if its not presented otherwise keeps current version.

Comment: @Borek `npm update` will update to the latest version based on your package.json, not regardless of it. If you have "express": "3.x" and you are on version 3.1.0, it will update to the latest 3.x tag. If there is a 4.x version, it will not install the latest.

Comment: So will **npm update** update a package in node_modules even if it is _not_ in `package.json`?

Comment: npm update also install the missing files with latest version, in case you have deleted the node_module folder for some reason, npm update will work like npm install too according to your package.json

Comment: @BennettMcElwee no, `package.json` is the main source of truth for what packages  and versions should be installed; either `npm install` and `update` will honour that file. Based on this, packages will be downloaded into `node_modules`. And **if** a `package-lock.json` is present, `install` will ensure the precise versions from that `-lock` will be reinstalled (this ensure multiple machines have the same exact deps); while `update` will update `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` according to the *semver* boundaries defined into `package.json`. No other magic based on `node_modules` content.

Comment: This was written long ago. Does all of this assume there is no `package-lock.json` file?

Answer (score 51):

In most cases, this will install the latest version of the module published on npm.

```
npm install express --save
```

or better to upgrade module to latest version use:

```
npm install express@latest --save --force
```

`--save`: Package will appear in your dependencies.

More info: [npm-install](https://npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-install.html)

Comment: `npm install express@latest --save --force` was exactly what I wanted.

Comment: In most cases? Any other cases?

Answer (score 16):

`npm update`: install and update with latest node modules which are in package.json

`npm install`: install node modules which are defined in package.json(without update)

Comment: Using npm version 6.9.0 I observe the following behavior: `npm update` will omit a large number of dependencies in `package-lock.json`. To have all required packages available and `package-lock.json` to be correct, I always have to execute `npm install` right after `npm update`.

Answer (score 12):

Many distinctions have already been mentioned. Here is one more:

Running `npm install` at the top of your source directory will run various scripts: `prepublish`, `preinstall`, `install`, `postinstall`. Depending on what these scripts do, a `npm install` may do considerably more work than just installing dependencies.

I've just had a use case where `prepublish` would call `make` and the `Makefile` was designed to fetch dependencies if the `package.json` got updated. Calling `npm install` from within the `Makefile` would have lead to an infinite recursion, while calling `npm update` worked just fine, installing all dependencies so that the build could proceed even if `make` was called directly.

Comment: One implication is that if you updated, for instance, your `redis` module, and `other_module` requires an older version of `redis`, `npm install other_module` will guarantee that `other_module` will use the older version. It may add `other_module/node_modules/redis` if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

`npm update` also installs the latest version of a package regardless of the checksum saved in `package-lock.json`. When depending on private repos the saved checksum can break so that `npm install` throws a mismatch error. `npm update` will ignore the checksum and install the latest version specified in `package.json`.

The error can look something like this:

```
npm WARN tarball tarball data for repo@git+ssh://git@github.com/company/repo.git#b2d8280dfb292c13c614352adra910f298a2a771 (sha512-36mxm1NMCHisdfsdfsdfsdsdf3NtFvwpzpjCEZfQTXmoi04B3qVrsTs1tnsdsdfsdfZNIK8lbEGVRVKcDX5u9pY7B==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
```