# Meteor error reffering 'uglify-js' on deployment to Modulus.IO

Tags: deployment, meteor, modulus.io

I use Modulus.IO to deploy my Meteor app.

When I am on the development environment there is no problem at all, not in the 'meteor' console nor in the browser js console. But when I deploy it to Modulos.IO, this error appears in Modulus:

```
Error: Can't find npm module 'uglify-js'. Did you forget to call 'Npm.depends' in package.js within the 'minifiers' package?
    at Object.Npm.require (/mnt/data/1/programs/server/boot.js:106:17)
    at Package (packages/minifiers/minifiers.js:1)
    at packages/minifiers.js:307:4
    at packages/minifiers.js:317:3
    at /mnt/data/1/programs/server/boot.js:155:10
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/mnt/data/1/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at /mnt/data/1/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
[2014-05-16T11:48:10.665Z] Application CRASH detected. Exit code 8.
[2014-05-16T11:48:12.326Z] Application restarted.

/mnt/data/1/programs/server/boot.js:186
}).run();
```

I have no minifiers package installed and no underscore.js as well.

Comment: I am having the same problem using demeteorizer to deploy my Meteor app. It has only started happening since upgrading from Meteor 0.8 to 0.8.1.3.

Comment: I cannot say I saw in which Meteor version it started to happen, but it was in one of the newer versions for sure.
And I still haven't found the answer for this problem.

Comment: I have found the solution to my problem - I forgot to type [`npm update`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478679/npm-install-vs-update-whats-the-difference). This installed all the newly required packages, like `uglify-js`. In my case I also had to upgrade `demeteorizer` too for an [unrelated reason](https://github.com/onmodulus/demeteorizer/issues/54#issuecomment-44154307).

Comment: I did this and nothing happened, not in the command moment nor in the modulus after re-deployment. Same error, but thanks man, was a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, good news.
That was some error between NPM and Modulus module version.
I've uninstalled NPM, Modulus module and stopped the deploy environment.
Then installed the latest version of NPM and installed the latest version of Modulus module.
Finally, I've made the deploy again and it's everything ok.

Thanks for all the attention.

P.S.: Remember to install Modulus module globally (-g).