# npm package from private github repo, install vs update (package.json)

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm, installation

I have already seen this question [npm-install-vs-update-whats-the-difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478679/npm-install-vs-update-whats-the-difference)

My question is around using install vs update for private github repo using `git+` urls.

I have a private github repo which is used in the grunt. This repo receives frequent updates. I installed this repo using `git+ssh` url as mentioned here [npm install git remote url](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

Everything works fine when installing. Problem comes when updating the package. As per my understanding and question mentioned above, npm updates the package to latest version when doing `npm install` but this doesnt seem to be case with package installed from github. I had to use `npm update` to get the latest version. I dont mind using `npm update` but I have observed that its slow compared to `npm install`. Can anyone put their thoughts why this might be happening.

My package.json looks like following

```
{
  "name": "My Project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    //Relevent package
    "my-tasks": "git+ssh://git@github.com:Flutterbee/my-tasks.git" 
  }
}
```

PS : Using npm 3.3.3 (if that makes difference)

Comment: Can you try what happens if you just write `"my-tasks": "Flutterbee/my-tasks"`? I also had buggy behaviors when installed packages from git.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I tried that now. Same result. Only difference was it started using `https` instead of `ssh`. Still have to do `npm update` to get latest chages.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with specifying the branch name with in your `package.json` like this

```
"my-tasks": "git+ssh://git@github.com:Flutterbee/my-tasks.git#master"
```