# Make npm fetch latest package from Git repo

Tags: node.js, git, npm

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33008102/npm-package-from-private-github-repo-install-vs-update-package-json).

A project has a dependency on a Git module which resides in a privately-hosted repository:

```
"dependencies": {
  "mymod": "git+https://mygitserver:8443/scm/od/mymod.git",
  ...
}
```

The intention is for this to be a snapshot dependency, so whenever any `mymod` code gets modified, the project pulls down the latest version.

The question is, what command should I properly use to update my project to the latest version of the module?

The only thing that I have found that works is:

```
rm -rf node_modules/mymod
npm install
```

Running `npm install` alone does nothing (given that it has been run once already), as noted by @Vishwanath in his question, because the module is already installed. `npm upgrade` is inappropriate, because I also have dependencies on a lot of other modules, and I do not want to upgrade them all to newer versions.

I guess I could explicitly version `mymod` and then update my local `package.json` with the new version whenever it changes, but that creates an ongoing maintenance task.

It seems like `npm` has enough information to determine when an upgrade is needed, because `node_modules/mymod/package.json` contains the last known head revision, which it could compare to the current head revision:

```
"gitHead": "b63f0df8ef...",
"_resolved": "git+https://mygitserver:8443/scm/od/mymod.git#b63f0df8ef..."
```

Does `npm` have a preferred way of handling snapshot dependencies like this?

Comment: Slightly better than deleting the local module is to rerun the explicit install command: `npm install "git+https://mygitserver:8443/scm/od/mymod.git"`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**UPDATE - 2021 - private package in development and production**

In my new project I tried my best to write my code to fit both production and development with a minimum changes, working with my private package was one of the challenges.

I wanted to work locally on my package so all changes would be applied right away without the need to manually update my package every single time like the solution below, but on production I wanted it to install a specific version of the package from my git when I do `npm install`.

So what I did was to use 2 different dependencies, 1 for production and 1 for development

`package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
  "package-name": "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.com:*git package/path*.git#1.0.0",
},
"devDependencies": {
  "package-name-dev": "file:*package path*"
}
```

Now, after having both of the packages, In development I need to use the dev package every time I'm calling the main package instead of doing lots of `if(isDev){...}` over all of my files.

I used the [module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias) package that allows me to alias a module once, and it will be applied for the whole project.

at the top of `app.js`:

```
const isDev  = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'),
      isProd = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production');

if (isDev) {
  const moduleAlias = require('module-alias');

  moduleAlias.addAlias('package-name', 'package-name-dev');
}
```

And that's it, now, when ever I `const pack = require('package-name')`, it will require the local package (dev) on development, and the main package on production.

***Note*** - in the main package I used a tag (#1.0.0) at the end of my git URL, I use the same package over multiple of my projects, and I wanted to make sure that I control the version of my package per project, so I can manually test newest version on older projects and nothing will break.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER - manually update packages**

I couldn't find any better way to do this, I ended up adding a script in the `package.json` that manually install the package I need.

Add a script to the `package.json` that will update the needed package:

```
"scripts": {
   "update:packages": "npm install git+ssh://git@GIT_URL_HERE#master"
}
```

While this is the same as manually updating the package, as @chris said in comments of the other answer, this is a lot easier and can be used with:

```
npm run update:packages
```

**NOTE** - The `#master` tag at the end will install the master branch, not optimal but it allows you to install the last version of the package without manually changing the tag each time.

**Update** - if you need this for development and the package in the private repository is something you work on locally (like me), you can simply link the package to the project, all changes will be shown right away without the need of reinstalling it, [more info on link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link):

```
cd /path/to/working/dir
npm link ../path/to/package/dir
```

**Update 2**
If you use Docker, `npm link` will not work inside the docker, this is because `link` is setting a soft link to your local npm folder.
To avoid this you will need to set the soft link **inside** the docker.

Answer (score 13):

You can manually update a package.

```
npm update mymod
```

This will update your package-lock.json with latest hash commit.

Answer (score 1):

I tried updating the version number in package.json but it still not update the package. Seems like the only way is to delete the old package each time.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my package.json file to sth like this which worked fine

```
"scripts": {
    .......
    "updateGit": "npm uninstall PACKAGE-NAME && npm install git+https://github.com/..../PACKAGE-NAME.git"
  },
```

then

```
npm run updateGit
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to update the version in package.json in mymod to make npm install the updated code.

Comment: The point is there is no version number in package.json - this is a snapshot dependency so the latest code should always be used.

Comment: As far as I know npm is very focused on version numbers. But I'm refering to updating the version in mymod, not in your main project. Can you make mymod autobump its version on commit or push?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Interesting idea. I'm 99% sure that `npm install` does not even connect to the Git server, but I'll try it.

Comment: I know for a fact that npm refused to install new code from github even when I tagged a new version when I forgot to update version in package.json

Comment: I tried updating the version in `package.json` within `mymod` as suggested. It makes no difference to `npm install`, which still does nothing. It does not even connect to the Git repostory. Only an explicit `npm install git+https://etc/mymod` forces it to pull the latest version.