# NPM pulling wrong version from GitHub

Tags: node.js, npm, package, versioning

I am struggling with npm:

I have 3 npm packages (typescript only), lets call them A (e.g. Server), B (e.g. Client) and C (e.g. stuff used across). All of them are saved in my GitHub. A and B are independent, C is included to both of them as a dependency via `"package-c": "git+ssh://git@github.com:myname/package-c.git#main"` (`main` is the only existing branch, tried with and without branch specification).

A and B have a pretty similar setup and package config, I don't believe that my issue derives from that.

The Issue: When I do `npm i` on A, it works totally fine, it installs the latest commit from GitHub. BUT when I do `npm i` on B something strange occurs: it installs a commit i pushed days ago!!

I cleared caches, deleted every node_modules folder, switches node versions, restarted, fetched again, reinstalled, checked every config, used cli/different IDEs, even made the package configs the same. It just won't work.

Can't explain this to me, so I neither have any idea what code to share with you guys. Such an issue never occurred.

I am thankful for any tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33008102/14101494) `npm update package-c`  and than `npm install` does the job.

Still no idea why `npm install` without updating worked for A and why B installed a commit which was pushed days ago … but at least it worked.