# What is the general step to update node_modules (`npm install` vs `npm update`) after switching a git branch?

Tags: node.js, npm, git-branch

Is it a general rule if we switch git branch often, and after that, we should just use

```
npm update
```

instead of

```
npm install
```

because `npm update` will be sufficient? (and that `update` is a lot faster than `install`)?

(Switching branch might include *upgrading or downgrading* a node module).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478679/npm-install-vs-update-whats-the-difference

Answer (score 0):

Yes npm update should be sufficient. In the case that someone commits a change to package.json adding dependency x on a branch, if you check out their branch and run npm update, you will have dependency x in your node_modules directory.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478679/npm-install-vs-update-whats-the-difference) for more information on why you would want to use update vs install.