# How to always get newest version when using * instead of version number in package.json?

Tags: npm, npm-install, npmjs

I have a private dependency on package.json and it should always install the latest version. So instead of the version, it's `*`.

```
"dependencies": {
   "@user/package": "*"
}
```

After the package was updated in npmjs it still installed old version with `npm i` if I enter exact version number instead of `*` - it installs a fresh version, which was published like a day ago.

I had a similar issue when the version was updated a minute ago at npmjs but now npmjs cache should be expired & updated with the new version, isn't it?

How can I avoid such issue and always get newest versions for everything with `*`?

I've tried `npm cache verify` `npm cache clean --force`. No luck.

Comment: @CodeCaster thanks for the link, probably yes. i had to use npm update to get updates even during initial installation when node_modules did not exist. Which i can't confirm now because i used npm i on each package already to get newest version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even during initial installation of dependencies it's necessary to use `npm update` instead of `npm install`.

This question talks more about `npm install` vs `npm update`

[npm install vs. update - what's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478679/npm-install-vs-update-whats-the-difference)

> Conclusion: The only big difference is that an already installed
>   module with fuzzy versioning ...
>
> - gets ignored by npm install
> - gets updated by npm update

Thanks CodeCaster for a link for correct command. But:

**The issue is still there**. Most of the time, it works every time. But. Just had another update when npm did not resolve to the newest version. Switching values form `*` to numbers for now. Seems like a bug for me.

Comment: Indeed, I tried to use * and it did not work as expected when I did `npm install`. Having internal components that are published is indeed painful with the versioning. I still haven't seen a leaner way to do it outside of putting a bat file on the root to do the `npm install @latest`.

Answer (score 9):

you can try to install with the packagename@latest keyword, but as far as i know you can only use this keyword in command line interface with npm install --save.

```
npm install --save mypackage@latest
```

after reading the doc here https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json
 i found you can write "latest" instead of any version number in a package.json file. This should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks but packages are already installed and there are many of them. I'm looking for a solution which would let me have latest versions w/o `npm i` command for ~15 packages each time I open a project on my dev machine. By npm docs `*` instead of version should do it but it doesn't.

Comment: ok, edited my answer, you can use "latest" as a version number apparently. just found that.

Comment: Kauyn `*` is valid version expresion and issue is not about it but about `npm install` command which i had to use `npm update` as answered by CodeCaster, thanks for support