# Why do I have to update npm every time I install a new library?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am not sure that this happens (will happen) every time I install a new library, but at least I have seen this many times now after installing a library with `npm`:

```
Update available 5.6.0 → 5.8.0   
     Run npm i -g npm to update
```

I do that, of course, and the next time I install a library it happens again. I think I did not see that when I started using `npm`.

What could be going on here?

(I am on Windows 10 when doing this. After updating `npm --version` says `5.8.0`. Next time I will check before...)

EDIT: Just checked with `npm --version` when I got the message to update. The version is 5.8.0, not 5.6.0. Quite strange.

Comment: Sounds like maybe the new npm path isn't sticking. Could be you need to update your path to point to the new one?

Comment: every time you give npm install (library), it automatically downloads the latest updated version I believe

Comment: @Catalyst Yes, something like that.

Comment: @Grijan Do you mean that `npm` is updated when I install a library?

Comment: @Leo sorry dude, i forgot to update you, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478679/npm-install-vs-update-whats-the-difference), if this is not clear, ping me here again , i will clarify you

Comment: @Leo yes it will, and after installing if the package manager has released a new version, then you should update it(provided you have already installed the package), if you install(for the first time) after a new version of the package is updated, then u will get the latest version. hope this clarifies you

Comment: Thanks @grijan, but I did not see anything about npm itself there. Did I miss something?

Comment: in the link? i do not follow you

Comment: There seems to be an issue with that version:
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/20063

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows note that there is a difference between running

```
npm install -g npm
```

when running as a normal user in a non-elevated command prompt, and running it in an elevated "Administrator" command prompt.

First, determine where npm is installed

```
where npm
```

If npm is installed under "Program Files", then you'll want to be in an elevated Administrator command prompt when you upgrade.  If npm is installed under your user's AppData folder, then you'll want to be running as your user in a non-elevated command prompt.

Comment: Thanks. There are actually two npm.cmd, one in `Program Files (x86)\` and one in `AppData\Roaming\npm\`. I will try updating npm as an "Administrator" next time.

Comment: `which npm` on Mac