# NPM Update with caret version doesn't bring in latest minor version (install does)

Tags: npm

I'm trying to learn NPM (and React). I tried migrating a demo site from React 15 to 16.

I ran `npm install --save react@^16.0.0` and it worked and updated my package.json file to "react":^16.0.0. I noticed that in package-lock.json, it didn't have the '^' so I added it and ran: `npm update react --save` and the version stays at 16.0.0 in both files while I'd expect it to update to 16.4.2.

If I run: `npm install react --save` it'll get the latest version and everything works. From this article it seems like the opposite should be true:

[npm install vs. update - what's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478679/npm-install-vs-update-whats-the-difference)

Can anyone shed light as to why this is happening?