# Check that NPM package.json and package-lock.json are compatible

Tags: npm, dependencies, package.json, package-lock.json

Is there a way to check if a `package-lock.json` file is compatible with `package.json` without running `npm install`?  Compatible means the versions specified `package.json` can be fulfilled by `package-lock.json`.

**Current approach**

I'm currently checking this by running `npm install` and checking if `package-lock.json` changed like so:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/my/codebase
cd codebase
npm install
if [[ git diff-index --quiet HEAD -- package-lock.json ]]; then
  echo 'ERROR: npm install changed package-lock.json'
fi
```

**Use-case**

I want to add a test in continuous integration to ensure that if a developer modifies `package.json` they also update `package-lock.json` accordingly.  The reason this is important is that our continuous integration uses `npm ci` instead of `npm install`.  `npm ci` only references `package-lock.json`, so if the developer doesn't update the lock file, the continuous integration setup won't match what they expect.

Comment: `npm ci` will fail if the package.json and the package-lock.json are not in sync, so your continuous integration is already testing your use case.

Can you please provide more information about the difference you are finding between your developer's setup and the CI one?

Comment: Yep, I verified this works for version numbers.  However, I found this not to be true when using a Git revision.  Repro and details at https://npm.community/t/npm-ci-doesnt-validate-versions-for-git-hashes-between-package-json-and-package-lock-json/10213

Answer (score 3):

As someone in the comments mentioned, there's the `npm ci` command, which will throw an error if `package.json` is not in sync with `package-lock.json`.

Here's what I use to "test" that they are on parity:

```sh
ERRORS=0
npm ci
if [[ "$?" -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "Dependency installation failed!"
    ERRORS=$(($ERRORS+1))
fi
```

I'm looking for a better way to do this since this actually removes the entire `node_modules` directory, confirms parity, and then proceeds to install the locked versions if all is well, but that takes some time depending on the number of packages.

Answer (score 0):

It took me few months to discover that `npm ci` is not your friend as it would miss to sync updated engines from package.json`into`package-lock.json`. Thus I think that the answer is` npm install --production`

All the kudos should go to https://stackoverflow.com/a/19824154/99834 which explains it in detail. For convenience I will mention the most important bits:

- `npm install` will install/update devDependencies unless `--production` flag is added
- `npm update` will ignore devDependencies unless `--dev` flag is added