# Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/rules/DescriptionDataMatcherRulePlugin' Require stack:

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js, webpack

I have webpack-cli installed on my laravel project. I don't know why first of all we need it to run my vue app but this is causing an error:

When I run **npm run dev** or **npm run hot**

```
[webpack-cli] Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/rules/DescriptionDataMatcherRulePlugin'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Viruss\Desktop\test-meme-library\meme-library\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\plugin-webpack5.js
- C:\Users\Viruss\Desktop\test-meme-library\meme-library\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\plugin.js
- C:\Users\Viruss\Desktop\test-meme-library\meme-library\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\Viruss\Desktop\test-meme-library\meme-library\node_modules\laravel-mix\src\components\Vue.js
- C:\Users\Viruss\Desktop\test-meme-library\meme-library\node_modules\laravel-mix\src\components\ComponentRegistrar.js
- C:\Users\Viruss\Desktop\test-meme-library\meme-library\node_modules\laravel-mix\src\Mix.js
- C:\Users\Viruss\Desktop\test-meme-library\meme-library\node_modules\laravel-mix\setup\webpack.config.js
- C:\Users\Viruss\Desktop\test-meme-library\meme-library\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js
- C:\Users\Viruss\Desktop\test-meme-library\meme-library\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\bootstrap.js
- C:\Users\Viruss\Desktop\test-meme-library\meme-library\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js
- C:\Users\Viruss\Desktop\test-meme-library\meme-library\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Viruss\Desktop\test-meme-library\meme-library\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\plugin-webpack5.js:6:42)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\Viruss\\Desktop\\test-meme-library\\meme-library\\node_modules\\vue-loader\\lib\\plugin-webpack5.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Viruss\\Desktop\\test-meme-library\\meme-library\\node_modules\\vue-loader\\lib\\plugin.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Viruss\\Desktop\\test-meme-library\\meme-library\\node_modules\\vue-loader\\lib\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Viruss\\Desktop\\test-meme-library\\meme-library\\node_modules\\laravel-mix\\src\\components\\Vue.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Viruss\\Desktop\\test-meme-library\\meme-library\\node_modules\\laravel-mix\\src\\components\\ComponentRegistrar.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Viruss\\Desktop\\test-meme-library\\meme-library\\node_modules\\laravel-mix\\src\\Mix.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Viruss\\Desktop\\test-meme-library\\meme-library\\node_modules\\laravel-mix\\setup\\webpack.config.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Viruss\\Desktop\\test-meme-library\\meme-library\\node_modules\\webpack-cli\\lib\\webpack-cli.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Viruss\\Desktop\\test-meme-library\\meme-library\\node_modules\\webpack-cli\\lib\\bootstrap.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Viruss\\Desktop\\test-meme-library\\meme-library\\node_modules\\webpack-cli\\bin\\cli.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Viruss\\Desktop\\test-meme-library\\meme-library\\node_modules\\webpack\\bin\\webpack.js'
  ]
}
```

> Vue is installed also vue-loader, can't understand why it can't find those files. Also, I looked at the node_modules everything is in there ...

Answer (score 246, accepted):

You need to update your vue-loader

```
npm update vue-loader
```

And if it is not installed, install it

```
npm i vue-loader
```

Comment: Dude after hours you saved my head from getting smashed to the wall... Jk now for real dude thanks!

Comment: solution worked for me also. Good find.

Comment: latest laravel 9 have this issue, and this solution fix it, thanks

Comment: This used to work for me. But now it is no longer anymore. Same error message persists. `vue-loader: 16.2.0`, `vue: 3.2.33`, `"laravel-mix": "^6.0.6"` on laravel 9

Comment: Removing `.vue()` from webpack.mix.js does it

Comment: not work for me...

Answer (score 15):

Laravel added the `15.9.7` version of Vue-loader by default.  I have to manually update the `vue-loader:^15.9.8` in the package JSON to solve the error.

Then do `yarn` and `yarn dev` or `npm install` and `npm run dev`

Comment: Thank you for good information about answer

Answer (score 7):

I had this error in my project. After searching for it, I discovered that I have to upgrade the Vue loader. And if not installed, go ahead and install it from [here](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/#manual-setup). So I add this line to my terminal in my project.

```
npm install -D vue-loader vue-template-compiler
```

Answer (score 5):

running

```
npm update vue-loader
```

should do the work just fine if the vue-loader package is already installed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I gave you a positive to counteract the negative. Because I believe that giving you  as a new member, a negative has been strict.

Answer (score 2):

Some of those updates are major releases. Running npm update won’t update the version of those. Major releases are never updated in this way because they (by definition) introduce breaking changes, and npm want to save you trouble.

Some times npm packages not gets installed properly, i used following method to resolve this problem:

**

- Delete node modules folder from your project.
- Execute following commands

1. npm install -g npm-check-updates
2. ncu -u
3. npm install/update.**

Answer (score 0):

For my particular case, I had to install webpack. `npm ci` revealed that there was a [package in package-lock.json that wasn't included in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64072283/2077884), and I had removed package-lock.json earlier to try and solve what ended up being a private npm repository issue. `npm install --save-dev webpack@^version.in.package-lock.json` fixed my issue, as `@vue/cli-service` depends on it, and some `vue.config.js` files in the project referenced it.