# Difference between `npm update` and `remove package-lock.json` plus `npm install`?

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json, package-lock.json, npm-update

What is essential difference between these commands, **except that** npm update modify package.json?

```
rm package-lock.json
npm install
```

```
npm update --dev
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm install vs. update - what's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478679/npm-install-vs-update-whats-the-difference)

Comment: @Raju No, but sure I have read this before I asked.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In `package-lock.json` basically the indirect dependencies are locked. The indirect dependencies mean those dependencies, that are not specified in the `package.json` of your project but they are the dependencies of your dependencies.

When `npm update --dev` is called some dependencies are updated in the `package.json`. After the entries are updated an install is called, this install updates in `package-lock.json` those thirdparties that are in connection with the modified ones in the `package.json`. This means that both the direct and indirect dependencies are updated in the `package-lock.json`. But only for those, that were modified in `package.json`.
The thirdparties that remained the same in the `package.json` won't be touched in the `package-lock.json`. (Both direct and indirect dependencies of them remain the same.)

When `rm package-lock.json` and `npm install` is called, then the information is lost about the indirect dependencies with the removing of the `package-lock.json`. As `npm install` is called, a new `package-lock.json` is generated and the indirect dependencies could be changed for all of your dependencies.

**Let's see an example for this.**

In `package-lock.json` we have an indirect dependency the `tslib: 1.9.0`.

```
"tslib": {
  "version": "1.9.0",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/tslib/-/tslib-1.9.0.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-f/qGG2tUkrISBlQZEjEqoZ3B2+npJjIf04H1wuAv9iA8i04Icp+61KRXxFdha22670NJopsZCIjhC3SnjPRKrQ=="
},
```

The `tslib` is a dependency of all Angular modules, that are specified directly in the`package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "8.2.12",
  "@angular/cdk": "~8.2.3",
  "@angular/common": "8.2.12",
  "@angular/compiler": "8.2.12",
  "@angular/core": "8.2.12",
  "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.27",
  "@angular/forms": "8.2.12",
  "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "8.2.12",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.2.12",
  "@angular/platform-server": "8.2.12",
  "@angular/router": "8.2.12",
  "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "8.1.1",
  "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
  "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
  "core-js": "^2.6.5",
  "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
  "jquery": "3.4.1",
  "oidc-client": "^1.9.0",
  "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
  "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
  "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.800.6",
  "@angular/cli": "8.3.18",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.2.12",
  "@angular/language-service": "8.2.12",
  "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.9",
  "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.6",
  "@types/node": "~11.10.5",
  "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
  "jasmine-core": "~3.3.0",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
  "karma": "^4.0.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
  "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.5",
  "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
  "typescript": "3.4.5"
},
"optionalDependencies": {
  "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
  "protractor": "~5.4.0",
  "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
  "tslint": "~5.9.1"
}
```

If we call `npm update --dev`, following changes are done:

```
+ bootstrap@4.5.0
+ core-js@2.6.11
+ popper.js@1.16.1
+ karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.5.4
+ karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter@2.0.6
+ codelyzer@5.2.2
+ karma@4.4.1
+ @types/jasmine@3.3.16
+ @types/jasminewd2@2.0.8
+ oidc-client@1.10.1
+ rxjs@6.5.5
```

We can see, that in the `package.json` the Angular dependencies are not touched. It follows that the `tslib` is also remained on version `1.9.0` in the `package-lock.json`.

However if we remove the `package-lock.json`, remove the `node_modules`, do the above updates in the `package.json` manually and call `npm install` we can see in the newly generated `package-lock.json` that the `tslib` is also updated to `1.12.0`. (If we do not remove the `node_modules` the same version could be put back in the `package-lock.json` as previously.)

**Conclusion**

So the difference is, that in case of `npm update --dev` only those direct and indirect dependencies are updated, which were in connection with the changed ones in the `package.json`. But in case of `rm package-lock.json` and `npm install` all indirect dependencies can change.