# Programmatically update node_modules to match package.json version?

Tags: node.js

I just learned that using `npm i` will not update packages to the version specified in the package.json if they are already installed. Is there a way to force an update for all modules to match the version specified in package.json?

For reference, here is how I'm calling to install from the code currently:

```
var Proc = child_process.execSync ('npm i', {
        cwd: cwd
      });
```

Comment: `npm i will not update packages to the version specified in the package.json`, any source?

Comment: @lastr2d2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478679/npm-install-vs-update-whats-the-difference

Comment: try `npm ci`, it will do a clean install using your package and package-lock.json

Comment: @FredStark that gives me the error "npm WARN prepare removing existing node_modules/ before installation" when it's run through code

Comment: that's not an error

Comment: or you could use https://www.npmjs.com/package/libnpm instead of `exec` to call npm functions

Comment: Also, you can tell npm to install a specific version in package.json by omitting the default `^` prefix. See docs for version specifiers here: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#dependencies

Comment: Using that flag does not seem to matter. npm ci is not deleted node_modules, so it's not installing new ones with the specified version